# How to rsync folder using gitlab-ci

Tags: rsync, gitlab

I try to sync my local files inside the folder named *dist* with the *root* folder of my ftp-account using `.gitlab-ci.yml`. While the job runs successfully, my ftp root folder remains empty.

I have created a ftp account, which has access to `httpdocs` only. I want my files to be copied inside httpdocs.

I am using this code to copy the files:

```
rsync -avh --delete --rsh="sshpass -p $PROD_FTP_PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "  ./dist/ $PROD_FTP_USER@my.ftpserver.de/
```

The command logs the following:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory dev-git@my.ftpserver.de
./
android-chrome-192x192.png

          4.69K 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
          4.69K 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=18/20)
android-chrome-256x256.png

          6.41K 100%    6.12MB/s    0:00:00  
          6.41K 100%    6.12MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=17/20)
app.css

          2.06K 100%    1.97MB/s    0:00:00  
          2.06K 100%    1.97MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, to-chk=16/20)

sent 62.95K bytes  received 423 bytes  126.74K bytes/sec
total size is 61.64K  speedup is 0.97
Job succeeded
```

I have read, that using `dist/` or `dist` makes a difference. I do not want to copy the folder but it files. Although I want to place these files in the root directory of my ftp account (which is `httpdocs/`).

What am I doing wrong and where are the files being copied right now, as I cannot see them using my ftp account?

**Another error message**:

When I try to send data to a random path, I receive the following error:

```
$ rsync -avh --progress --delete --rsh="sshpass -p $PROD_FTP_PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no " ./dist $PROD_FTP_USER@my.ftpserver.de/httpdocs/yellowstorm
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/builds/fyd/fyd-presite/dev-git@my.ftpserver.de/httpdocs/yellowstorm" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674) [Receiver=3.1.1]
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for remote source/destination in rsync is `[<user>@]<host>:[path]` So minimally this must be `example.com:` ie the `:` is important.

Your remote does not have the `:` so rsync will be copying the files to a local directory called `$PROD_FTP_USER@my.ftpserver.de` (you can confirm by running an ls in the build plan) instead you should use `$PROD_FTP_USER@my.ftpserver.de:/` this will copy into the root of the remote (the servers root not the ftp root since you are using ssh). Or `$PROD_FTP_USER@my.ftpserver.de:` will copy into the user's home directory.